# Error Unable to save measure for metric pdf-data on component :Sonar Exception?

Tags: mysql, linux, maven, sonarqube

I have a Jenkins Job that runs SonarRunner on a Maven project composed of several modules i'm using msql db for sonar. The build fails showing that

[ERROR] Unable to save measure for metric [pdf-data] on component [com.XX:xxx-parent]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3.1:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX-parent: Unable to save measure for metric [pdf-data] on component [com.XX:XXX-parent]:
[ERROR] ### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (3676748 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
[ERROR] ### The error may involve org.sonar.api.database.model.MeasureMapper.insertData-Inline
[ERROR] ### The error occurred while setting parameters
[ERROR] ### SQL: INSERT INTO measure_data (measure_id, snapshot_id, data)     VALUES (?, ?, ?)
[ERROR] ### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (3676748 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3.1:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX-parent: Unable to save measure for metric [pdf-data] on component [com.XXX:XXX-parent]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error as well. The MySQL database that your SonarQube is using only allows LOB contents up to 1 MB by default and the content it is trying to save is larger than that as stated in the error message.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (3676748 > 1048576).
```

The solution is that you need to increase the `max_allowed_packet` setting for the MySQL instance the SonarQube is using.

```
You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

Instructions can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/packet-too-large.html).

Start the server with the desired setting, i.e. `mysqld --max_allowed_packet=16M` for 16 MB max.

Or more permanently, modify the config file (my.cnf on Linux systems, possibly my.ini on Windows) by adding the setting under the `[mysqld]` section.

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```